# Access a method from another class in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Is there a way where you can call a method from another class? I searched the internet and i found that you need to do something along the lines of `i.putExtra ("Total Score",total);`, But what does this mean? What are the parameters being passed through here?

In my First Class it has an `onClick` method and a `getTotal` method, the total has been calculated in other parts of my code:

Below is my code:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {

                 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Score.class);
                 i.putExtra ("Total Score",total); // Is this right?
                 startActivity(i);

            }
        }


    public int getTotal(){
        return total;
    }
```

I want to call the `getTotal` method in my second class, so that it displays my total in the second class. What would i have to do to get the total?

Thank You.

Comment: yes what you are doing is right. pass value using intent

Comment: Do you really want to start a new Activity or just call a Method from a Class, which is not an Activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two questions here actually.

- Calling method of activity from other one.

You can easily do this in any object oriented language either by declaring method static and public or making new object out of the owner class and calling it on other class but since its activity it is really bad idea.

```
public static returnType yourMethod()
```

- Accessing calculated value or passing it to another activity.

Thats what `putExtra()` for they allow you pass primitives and objects (must implement `Serializable` interface) and use it in other activiies. You put your object with `Intent` and check extra on other activity `onCreate` method

```
Intent intent = Intent(this, YouActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("SPECIAL_TAG", data);
```

and in other activity

```
getIntent().getXExtra("SPECIALTAG", defaultValue);
```

Better to create SPECIALTAG as

```
public static final String
```

Answer (score 1):

```
i.putExtra ("Total Score",total);
```

I guess you have the value in total variable and assume its a string value.

It can be an  int value since you talk about score also

You can have a look @ putExtra and the get methods and use the one suitable to you @

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Yes its the right way. Passing values between activities using intent

the first param is the key ie Total Score

The second param is the value a string total

You will be using the same key to retrieve the string value

```
String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("Total Score");
```

If its a int value

```
int value = getIntent().getIntExtra("Total Score",0);
```